# Cocos2d Composition using CCSpriteBatchNode

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d, component-based, objective-c

I'm making a game in objective-c using cocos2d. I have the following:

```
@interface Player : CCNode
{
    CCSprite *mySprite;
    CCSpriteBatchNode *sceneSpriteBatchNode;
    //...
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) CCSprite *mySprite;
- (id)initWithSpriteBatch:(CCSpriteBatchNode *)_spn;
-(void)updateStateWithDeltaTime:(ccTime)deltaTime andListOfGameObjects:(CCArray*)listOfGameObjects;
@end


@implementation Player
- (id)initWithSpriteBatch:(CCSpriteBatchNode *)_spn
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        sceneSpriteBatchNode = _spn;
        mySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"player_image.png"];
        [_spn addChild:mySprite];
    }
    return self;
}
//....
@end
```

Now in the layer I would do:

```
//...
Player *player = [[Player alloc] initWithSpriteBatch:sceneSpriteBatchNode];
[player release];

-(void) update:(ccTime)deltaTime
{
    CCArray *listOfGameObjects = [sceneSpriteBatchNode children];
    for (CCNode *tempChar in listOfGameObjects) {
        [tempChar updateStateWithDeltaTime:deltaTime andListOfGameObjects:listOfGameObjects];
    }
}
```

However, you can only add CCSprite to the spritebatchnode, that way I can't update my custom classes. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a flaw in your architecture there. The Player should not be a subclass of `CCNode` (or any cocos2d node class for that matter).

The `CCNode` is only the visual representation of your player-character, therefore your Player class should have a `CCNode` as member (or property as it's called in Objective-C). This makes your architecture much more flexible. You could implement a component-based architecture, where your node is part of a "VisualComponent", or you could have an inheritance-based architecture where you inherit from a "GameEntity" base-class etc. But inheriting from `CCNode` is a bad idea and will definitely hurt you in the long run.

**Update:** As requested in the comments, here's a short guide how you could refactor your code using a Player class that inherits from `NSObject` and implements a GameEntity Protocol. For a more complete documentation of protocols, read the [Objective-C docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html).

Protocols are much like interfaces known from other programming-languages. A very simple protocol could look like this:

```
#import "cocos2d.h"

/**
 Protocol for a game entity
 */
@protocol GameEntityProtocol<NSObject>

/** Visual representation of the entity */
@property(assign) CCNode* node;

/** Update method */
-(void) update:(ccTime)dt;
@end
```

Your Player class could then be implemented like this:

```
#import "GameEntityProtocol.h"

// Player interface
@interface Player : NSObject<GameEntityProtocol>
{
    // player related members
}
@end

// Player implementation
@implementation Player

@synthesize node;

-(void) dealloc
{
    [self setNode: nil];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void) update:(ccTime)dt
{
    // do something.. update node position etc.
}
@end
```

And finally in your "Level" or "Game-World" you would have something like the following (note that you could also move the initialization of the player-node to the players init method, but it's easier to keep everything "outside" so you could read stuff from a data-file etc.):

```
// in your init method or where you load the level
// entities is a class member of type NSMutableArray*
entities = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 4];
Player *player = [[Player alloc] init];
[player setNode:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"player_image.png"]];
[sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild: player.node];
[entities addObject:player];

// update loop could look like this
-(void) update:(ccTime)deltaTime
{
    for (id<GameEntityProtocol> entity in entities) {
        [entity update:deltaTime];
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I read a lot and people say it's better composition than inheritance based games in cocos2d.

Comment: But what you're doing *is* inheritance based. You're inheriting from `CCNode` and that's clearly *less* composition than having a player class that has a `CCNode` as a property.

Comment: So what does the player class has to be? Just an NSObject? What's the point in adding a CCNode as a propery if I already have a CCSprite. I still won't be able to add my class to the spritebatchnode.

Comment: Yes, you inherit from `NSObject`. Then you have `Player.node` which is your `CCNode` and you set that to your sprite-batchnode. You could also have a `GameEntity` Protocol which will be implemented by your game-entity-classes, so you can easily update all your game-entities in a loop.

Comment: OK, I could also use an Array and add all my objects and update this array instead of the spritebatchnode too...

Comment: @marcg11 you should do that anyway.. there might be sprites in your batch that don't need updating at all (eg. parts of the level etc.)

Comment: An example of protocols adapted in my case would be pretty much appreciated, they are new to me.

Answer (score 0):

you can add any class inherited from of `CCNode` as a child of another `CCNode` instance.

player is a inherited from `CCNode` and CCLayer is also inherited from `CCNode`, so there is no need for a `CCSpriteBatchNode` instance in there, you can directly add player instance to your layer!

```
-(void) update:(ccTime)deltaTime
{
    CCArray *listOfGameObjects = [sceneSpriteBatchNode children];
    for (CCNode *tempChar in listOfGameObjects) {
        [tempChar updateStateWithDeltaTime:deltaTime andListOfGameObjects:listOfGameObjects];
    }
    [self addChild:player];
}
```

`CCSpriteBatchNode` provides better performance only to render multiple sprites with *same texture*, so if player does not use same texture as other objects in the scene you can't use an sprite batch! but you can define player class to inherit `CCSprite` instead of `CCNode`. this way you can attach it to the existing `sceneSpriteBatchNode` object.

Comment: Not if he's using a batch node.. which is preferable for better performance. Also you wouldn't add children inside the update loop.

Comment: @bummzack batch node is only providing better performance if player shares the same texture as other objects in the scene!

Comment: Yup, I'm using spriteBatchNode. I'm rendering 70 sprites aprox..